# zlib decompression - can't find header

Tags: php, python, gzip, zlib, compression

I'm currently working on a project to scan aztec code travel tickets, but I can't seem to decompress the scanned code afterwards. I've tried python and PHP, but both says that my data is not valid.

```
#UT011186000010,kOåïý|~`Míý-ú´ó ÿÃñ«'öÙÊ¨©Ýãåy÷ä0213xÚUAkÃ0
ÿÏ'ÉvìcG+6ç°]J!YWÚ&ÐAÿýdCG&°áÞ{R·}~Z&à(ø.
¥Èâ<¹ZhÙ~7Ý6¯ïjâà^3dõiþÝ¸ï§ó÷qº\ÕéTi«¹l(biÄÕíÔö_CÝêÖ !4u¥0Uyé/
øOÄm*¢vYï£vs:ü§Ï«1ëÛîOe*e*iÍÇ41Â
ß/+ô çäì<þQ¨7kÉ[N¿öKø
```

Hex code of data

```
23 55 54 30 31 31 31 38 36 30 30 30 30 31 30 2c 02 14 6b 05 4f c3 a5 c3 af c3 bd 7c 7e c2 87 60 4d c3 ad c3 bd 2d 19 c3 ba c2 b4 c3 b3 20 14 02 14 11 c2 9c c3 bf 1a c3 83 c3 b1 c2 ab 27 c3 b6 c3 99 c3 8a c2 88 c2 a8 c2 a9 c3 9d c3 a3 c3 a5 79 c3 b7 c3 a4 30 32 31 33 78 c3 9a 55 c2 8e 41 6b c3 83 30 0c 0d 0a c3 bf c2 8a c3 8f c2 83 c2 92 27 c3 89 76 c3 ac 63 c2 99 47 07 2b 14 36 c3 a7 c2 b0 5d 4a 21 59 57 c3 9a 26 c3 90 c2 95 41 c3 bf c3 bd 64 43 47 26 c2 b0 c3 a1 c2 93 c3 9e 7b 52 c2 b7 7d 7e 5a 26 10 c3 a0 c2 84 28 c3 b8 2e 0d 0a c2 a5 c2 97 c3 88 c3 a2 3c c2 8b c2 b9 17 05 02 c2 83 5a 68 c3 99 7e 37 c2 8c c3 9d 36 c2 af c2 97 c3 af 6a c3 a2 c3 a0 5e 1f 33 03 64 c3 b5 05 10 69 c2 90 c3 be c3 9d c2 b8 c3 af c2 a7 c3 b3 c3 b7 71 c2 ba 5c c3 95 c3 a9 54 69 c2 ab c2 b9 6c c2 80 28 12 62 69 c3 84 c3 95 c3 ad c3 94 1f c3 b6 5f 43 0f c3 9d c2 8e c3 aa c3 96 c2 99 20 21 34 75 c2 a5 30 55 79 c3 a9 2f c2 94 0d 0a c3 b8 4f c3 84 6d 03 2a c2 a2 76 c2 9a 59 c3 af c2 a3 76 73 3a c3 bc 0c 17 c2 93 c2 a7 c3 8f c2 ab 31 c3 ab c3 9b c3 ae 08 4f 65 2a 65 2a 69 c2 93 c3 8d c3 87 34 0e c2 86 16 31 c3 82 c2 8b c2 9d 0d 0a c3 9f 2f 2b c3 b4 20 14 c3 a7 c3 a4 c3 ac c2 9c 3c c3 be 51 c2 a8 37 6b c3 89 5b 4e c2 bf c2 98 c3 b6 4b c3 b8 0d 0a
```

Python returns

```
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

PHP returns

```
PHP Warning:  gzinflate(): data error
```

I cannot find the header and the body of the above data. I've also tried using gzip.

Comment: Relevant: [What does a zlib header look like?](//stackoverflow.com/q/9050260)

Comment: I see a potential start further on at the `78` byte, but why do you think this is zlib compressed?

Comment: There is no deflate compressed data in there. In fact, it doesn't appear to be compressed at all.